# Build-in Messaging System, Admin to all members

Tags: php, mysql

My website consist of a build-in messaging system, which a user can send message to another user and view it within the website. It's some sort of Facebook messaging but it's not using email address, just user to user kind of messaging service within the website.

My column for this mailbox table is mailbox_id, memberid, sender_id, sent_date, subject, body, is_unread, is_read, is_deleted.

When a user(memberid=1) send to another user(memberid=2), the mailbox_id would be an Auto-increment, memberid would be the id of the receiver and the sender_id would be user who sends the message which is "memberid=1". Hope you get the point.

However, here comes my problem. If I'm an Admin user and would like to send a message to "all" the members within my site, I'm not sure how to store that in my table. I could, of course create each message for each member. Let's say if there are 1000 members, there would be new 1000 rows in that table. How can I avoid doing this? I just want to have one new row in that table and all the users can see this message.

I was thinking of using memberId=0 and all the members can see this message since there will be no member using that id=0. But however, how can I track if one member deleted the massage? or seen that message? The column "is_deleted" can only be used by one user. 1=deleted and 0=not deleted.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**memberId=0** I belive is a good idea but to track if which member deleted the message? or seen that message? you can add two more columns in the table `deleted_by` and `seen_by`. make them the text field. and in `seen_by` keep all the `membersid` seprated by comma so that in front end you can take the value who have seen it or not and same you might do for `deleted_by`

**Alternative** way could be you can create a different table for sending the message to multiple members if in case you want a few message to send to multiple members and not all and not one.

Comment: If I create deleted_by and seen_by field, would it make my database to become slow? Lets say if I have like 1 million users, and to store all that amount of number to just that column? Thanks

Comment: It might effect the speed but very nominal. Have a look on the data type [TEXT and BLOB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html)

Comment: Thanks. I guess this is the only solution I have right now.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've found a solution to this by creating two different tables as suggested by @Mohit Shrivastava the alternative way. Below is my structure.

```
mailbox: id, sender_id, subject, body
mailbox_status: id, mailbox_id, recipient_id, is_read, is_deleted, sent_at
```

Correct me if anyone has better ideas. Thanks!!